# c# regex expression to find MACRO(L"TextW") or MACRO("TextA")

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to do a preprocessing on my source code (C++) and i'm trying to find strings that match the pattern :

```
MACRO(L"TextW")
```

OR

```
MACRO("TestA")
```

But my regex returns something different when being feed with (opposed to the example above):

```
MACRO(L"")
```

OR

```
MACRO("")
```

The preprocessing is being done in c#
The regex being used is

```
Regex.Match(text,"MACRO\\(*(L?)(\"?)(.*?[^\\\\])(\"?)*\\)");
```

But when handling the empty form of the macro the regex returns Grouping[3] = "\"" and Grouping[4] = "" instead of returning : Grouping[3] = "" and Grouping[4] = "\""

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why have you added some asterisk here `\\(*` and here `(\"?)*`?

Comment: The text might be: MARCO( "" ) , i might have been mistaken, and for now it's the closest thing i have that is working it just doesn't handle the empty string case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle inputs like this (`MACRO(L"Text A\" ")`) using negative lookbehind.

Also, you are making almost everything is optional in your regex using `?` sign. Here I am just making the `L` is optional.

Try this one:

```
string text = "MACRO(L\"TestA \\\"B\")";
Match match = Regex.Match(text, "MACRO\\(L?\"(.*?)(?<!\\\\)\"\\)");
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```